# Wordpress PHP | get_permalink() stripping slashes. Cant add extra slash

Tags: php, wordpress

I have social media buttons to share a URL. My code looks something like

```
$socialURL = get_permalink();

//trying to add extra slash here
$socialURL = str_replace('https://', 'https:///', $socialURL);

$facebookURL = 'https://facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=' . $socialURL;
```

My expected URL: https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https%3A%2F%2Fpillartopost.online

where %2F are the 2 slashes

Result URL: https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https%3A%2Fpillartopost.online%2Fnews%2Fwater-heating-systems%2F

where there is only one %2F slash.

For some reason my str_replace method is not doing anything. I have looked through wordpress docs for other solutions and nothing was working, and this definitely seems like the most simple solution. Why would that not add an extra slash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably, using `trailingslashit` with

php query builder function could solve the problem:

```
$social_url        = trailingslashit( get_permalink() );
$facebook_base_url = 'https://facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php';
$facebook_query    = http_build_query(
    [
        'u' => $social_url
    ]
);
$facebook_url      = "$facebook_base_url?$facebook_query";
```

According to trailingslashit docs:

> Appends a trailing slash. Will remove trailing forward and backslashes
> if it exists already before adding a trailing forward slash. This
> prevents double slashing a string or path...

Comment: it looks like the trailingslashit was unneccessary. The query builder function alone was enough to add both slashes. For some reason without using the query builder to generate a URL encoded query string, a slash was getting stripped. http_builld_query was what I was looking for :)